# Javascript работает только в IE9,но не работает в chrome и др браузерах

Tags: javascript, html, svg, google-chrome

скрипт js должен увеличивать масштаб документа. Я новичок в этой теме,поэтому прошу помощи
svg вставлен в html через `<object id="8x1" data="... .svg"> вызов функции <input type="image" src=".. .gif" name="zoomInBtn" onclick=zoomIn("8X1")>`

```
function zoomIn(obj) {
    var zoomLevel = 6;
var xbegin = 0;
var ybegin = 0;
var coords;
var i;
     var svgDoc=document.getElementById(obj).contentDocument;
     var rootElement = svgDoc.documentElement;
    var viewbox = rootElement.getAttribute("viewBox");
    var coords  = viewbox.split(/ /);
    if (zoomLevel >= 1) {
        zoomLevel -= 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
            coords[i] *= 0.8;
        } 
        if (xbegin > 0 && ybegin > 0) {
            coords[0] = xbegin - coords[2]/2;
            coords[1] = ybegin - coords[3]/2;
        }
        return rootElement.setAttribute("viewBox", coords.join(" "));
    }
}
```

Comment: `ebject` - ну логично, что не работает.

Comment: там опечатка в html прописан <object ..></object>.все равно не работает

Comment: Тогда меняй свойства, а не атрибуты.